# prettyphoto displaying image fullsize in iframe

Tags: jquery, iframe, prettyphoto

i have a site where the thumbnails are located in the iframe, currently when they click the thumbnail it only opens as large as the iframe, how do i make it so when the image is clicked it appears fullscreen of the whole site and not just the iframe area?
im using the prettyphoto script

here is the thumbnail page i uploaded to show the problem, when i click a thumbnail it only appears in fullscreen at the size of the iframe? (my content area)

http://callofdutylink.freehostia.com/

Comment: Is there a reason you are using an iframe?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot take anything in the iframe out of the frame. The iframe is the limit for all objects located within it.

instead of an iframe use a DIV and JQUERY to do what you are doing now

```
<div id="DynamicFrame"></div>

$('#DynamicFrame').load('htmlPageToLoad.html');
```

Comment: The div with the id DynamicFrame is a place holder.
$('#DynamicFrame').load('your.html');    <<-- this command will load what is in your.html file into the place holder div.

Comment: which files would i place this code into? (sorry web newbie). i have my index.htm which is the main site, and the gallery.htm which is the iframe for that page. also the prettyphoto js files

Comment: You need to read about the command http://api.jquery.com/load/. Also if the example and explanation is not enough then you need to goto http://www.w3schools.com/ and learn at least the basics. Copy past learning is ok but you should know what you copy and paste do.